# How to calculate difference between datetime within a group in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a `df` sorted by `AccountID` and `PurchaseDate`. What I want to do is calculate and create new column of the difference between `PurchaseDate`that are in each group of `AccountID`.

```
AccountID       PurchaseDate                 Price
| 113        2018-09-01 22:56:30              13|
| 113        2018-09-02 22:56:30              19|
| 114        2018-09-01 22:56:30              20|
| 114        2018-09-03 22:56:30              25|
```

to

```
AccountID       PurchaseDate                 Price          DateDiff
| 113        2018-09-01 22:56:30              13              null|
| 113        2018-09-02 22:56:30              19               1  |
| 114        2018-09-01 22:56:30              20              null|
| 114        2018-09-03 22:56:30              25               2  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
df['DateDiff'] = df.groupby('AccountID')['PurchaseDate'].\
                    diff().apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

Comment: You could also do `...diff().dt.days`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example of how you could do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'AccountID': [113, 113, 114, 114],
                   'PurchaseDate': ['2018-09-01 22:56:30',
                                    '2018-09-02 22:56:30',
                                    '2018-09-01 22:56:30',
                                    '2018-09-03 22:56:30'],
                   'Price': [13, 19, 20, 25]})

df['PurchaseDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PurchaseDate'])
df['DateDiff'] = df.groupby('AccountID').PurchaseDate.diff().fillna(0)
#    AccountID  Price        PurchaseDate DateDiff
# 0        113     13 2018-09-01 22:56:30   0 days
# 1        113     19 2018-09-02 22:56:30   1 days
# 2        114     20 2018-09-01 22:56:30   0 days
# 3        114     25 2018-09-03 22:56:30   2 days
```

Open to comments.